# Use different columns in dataset for networkD3 linkDistance and linkWidth

Tags: javascript, r, networkd3

Is it possible to use different columns in your dataset for the linkDistance and the linkWidth parameters in `forceNetwork`? In the examples listed, it uses JS("function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); }"). But I would want to use value for linkWidth and another column for linkDistance, or vice versa. I imagine there is a Javascript way to do thus, but I am not very skilled in Javascript.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(networkD3)

data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

MisLinks$linkDistance <- round(runif(nrow(MisLinks), 1, 10))
MisLinks$linkWidth <- round(runif(nrow(MisLinks), 0, 5))

fn <- forceNetwork(
  Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source",
  Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
  Group = "group", opacity = 1, zoom = TRUE,
  linkDistance = JS("function(d) { return d.linkDistance; }"),
  linkWidth = JS("function(d) { return d.linkWidth; }")
)

# add back in the `linkDistance` and `linkWidth` vectors/columns 
# because they will get stripped out by `forceNetwork`
fn$x$links$linkDistance <- MisLinks$linkDistance
fn$x$links$linkWidth <- MisLinks$linkWidth

fn
```